# Finding normal components of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

If
\begin{align}
\notag
A_{1}=c_{1}y_{1}^{2}y_{2}^{2}u(u+2t)(u+y_{2}^{2})\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\notag
A=-c_{11}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}-c_{12}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}-\frac{u(u+2t)}{u+y_{2}^{2}}(c_{8}(u+y_{1}^{2})+c_{1}y_{1}y_{2})\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{1}},
\end{align}
span tangent space of some manifold,

how can we find a normal component of a vector
\begin{align}
\notag
C=k(\frac{c_{14}y_{1}y_{2}}{u+y_{1}^{2}}+\frac{c_{12}y_{1}^{3}y_{2}^{3}}{(u+y_{1}^{2})^{3}}+\frac{c_{13}y_{1}^{3}y_{2}^{3}}{(u+y_{1}^{2})^{3}}-\frac{u+y_{2}^{2}}{u+y_{1}^{2}}c_{7}-\frac{y_{1}y_{2}}{u+y_{1}^{2}}c_{16})\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}+kc_{16}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}+(-\frac{1}{2}(u+y_{1}^{2})\frac{y_{1}}{\sqrt{1+4t}}-\frac{1}{2}y_{1}y_{2}\frac{y_{2}}{\sqrt{1+4t}}-y_{1}y_{2}^{2}+kc_{4})\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{1}}+(-\frac{1}{2}y_{1}y_{2}\frac{y_{1}}{\sqrt{1+4t}}-\frac{1}{2}(u+y_{2}^{2})\frac{y_{2}}{\sqrt{1+4t}}-(u+y_{2}^{2})y_{2}+k(c_{4}\frac{u+y_{2}^{2}}{y_{1}y_{2}}-c_{2}\frac{u+y_{2}^{2}}{u+y_{1}^{2}}+c_{4}\frac{y_{1}y_{2}}{u+y_{1}^{2}}+c_{3}\frac{y_{1}y_{2}u(u+2t)}{u+y_{1}^{2}}-c_{3}\frac{(u+y_{2}^{2})u(u+2t)}{y_{1}y_{2}})\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{2}}.
\end{align}
Here $k=(c_{1}y_{1}^{2}y_{2}^{2}u(u+2t)(u+y_{2}^{2}))^{2}$, $u$ is a function depending on $t=\frac{1}{2}(y_{1}^{2}+y_{2}^{2})$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how $B_1, B$ are relevant here.  Did you leave out some text by mistake?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I will delete it.